# Change style of printing acronyms with glossaries package

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the glossaries package to define my acronyms and print them out. I'm using this style:

```
\newglossarystyle{super3colleft}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\tablehead{}\tabletail{}%
     \begin{supertabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}lp{\glsdescwidth}p{\glspagelistwidth}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3 & ##5\\}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
     &
     \glssubentryitem{##2}%
     \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4 & ##6\\}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{ & &\\}%
}
```

to print them out via

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=super3colleft]
```

and to get some indentation of the acronyms, looks like this:
[image]

Is there any way to make the red one full of text instead of breaking the text, and to change th blue indentation-width and the height between two groups (purple color)? thanks a lot!

**EDIT**:
This as a working minimal example?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{X}{type=\acronymtype, name={XY}, description={blablabla asdkjh asdkjh aksjdh kajsdha ksjdh as dkha sdh}}
\newglossaryentry{Xb}{type=\acronymtype, name={XY2}, description={basdasd sdh}}
\newglossaryentry{y}{type=\acronymtype, name={Y}, description={foobar}}
\newglossaryentry{yb}{type=\acronymtype, name={Y2}, description={foo asd asd asd asdbar}}
\newglossaryentry{z}{type=\acronymtype, name={Z}, description={foo asd asd asd asdbar}}

\newglossarystyle{super3colleft}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\tablehead{}\tabletail{}%
     \begin{supertabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}lp{\glsdescwidth}p{\glspagelistwidth}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3 & ##5\\}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
     &
     \glssubentryitem{##2}%
     \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4 & ##6\\}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{ & &\\}%
}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=super3colleft]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide full minimal examples.

You create a new style by using `supertabular` with three columns. The first one is the short form, the second one is the description and the last is the page.

To modify the width you have to change the formating of the columns like a normal array-environment.

```
\usepackage{linegoal}
.....
 \newglossarystyle{super3colleft}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\tablehead{}\tabletail{}%
     \begin{supertabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace*{3cm}p{\linegoal}@{}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3 \\}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
     &
     \glssubentryitem{##2}%
     \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4 \\}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{ & \\}%
}
```

Comment: Marco thanks, I provided a minimal example above!

Answer (score 1):

To turn off the larger vertical gaps between each alphabetic cluster, change:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{ & &\\}%
```

to:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}% no extra line skip between clusters
```

You can then play with the vertical space between each entry by, for example, using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}` directly before calling `\printglossary`.